# Trying to get data attribute but returning undefined

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

**UPDATE: Sorry everyone, but this was a mistake on my part. I was calling the wrong ID in the data-target than the actual ID of the div i wanted to scroll to... hence the error!
I feel incredibly stupid, and sorry for wasting everyone's time. I Would delete the question, but it won't let me.**

---

I want to be able to create a simple JS function to smoothscroll from any div to any target div.

The way I want to do this is by detect the function when the *smooth scroll* class is added, and to have the target div specified by `data-target="#elementID"`.

```
<div class="smooth-scroll" data-target="targetDiv">Source link</div>

// Elsewhere on the page
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

But when I try using the below function, all I see when clicking on the source is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

```
$('.smooth-scroll').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+target).offset().top,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuart'    
    }, 1000);
});
```

I think the problem is that it's not getting the value of `target`. Is this correct, or is there something else?

Annoyingy, when I tried to create a jsFiddle, it works - so what on earth is going on? https://jsfiddle.net/rv0nmb44/

Comment: `event` isn't defined

Comment: Can you console out target and let us know what it says?

Comment: You're using jQuery, so you could use `$(this).data('target')` or `$(this).attr('data-target')` to assign `target` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Vivick `target = "before-after-slider"` which is what is inside data-target in the source. So clearly, it's not that then.

Comment: Like J. Titus said, `event` isn't defined, just add `event` as a parameter of the function

Comment: OKay, so I've changed my code to the answer provided below, which includes the `e`, but I still get `cannot read property of top`, regardless of `.top()` or `.top`. Can someone just try and explain what the error means? It's saying it can't read property `top` of undefined. IS the problem with top or the target?

Comment: For third time: $('.smooth-scroll').click(function(event) { - edit please.

Comment: @Roy I had done this, and even just said I had changed it. That wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a middle div block between the first and the target div (the blue box). It seems to correctly get the `top` property, as you can see.

In case this would not work, can you provide further details, like a live snippet of your non-working code?

```js
$('.smooth-scroll').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var top = $('#'+target).offset().top;
    console.log(top);
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: top,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuart'    
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="smooth-scroll" data-target="targetDiv">Source link</div>

<div style="height: 300px; background-color: blue;"></div>

<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything different, still receiving the error about `top`